# corrupted ELF header/section after extract from eclipse bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, elf

I need help with the following problem:

I have two different eclipse products, which use the same bundle where the linux executable is located, but use different eclipse plugins (3.5 and 3.7) from the target platform. Both running with:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-ea-b06)
```

on a 32bit Debian-system.

Both applications extract the executable from the bundle with `bundle.getEntry()` and put it in a directory via FileInputStream -> FileWriter.

Then the executable get invoked. In one case it works perfectly while the other does not. For version 3.5 (the working case), `$:file myFile` says following:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

and for version 3.7 (the non-working case), `$:file myFile` says following:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), corrupted program header size, corrupted section header size
```

They are using the same OS, JRE and Bundle, but what is destroying my ELF-Metadata?
I don't know anywhere else to look. Is it a Java problem? Eclipse? Libraries?

Here the copy-method:

```
URL url = bundle.getBundle(path);
inputStream = url.openStream();
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path);

int in;
while ((in = inputStream.read()) != -1)
fileWriter.write(in);

inputStream.close();
fileWriter.close();

new File(path).setExecutable(true, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `FileWriter` for binary data. Use `FileOutputStream` instead.

`Reader`s and `Writer`s are for textual data, they work with `char`s, whereas `InputStream`s and `OutputStream`s are for binary data, they work with `byte`s. Conversion between `char`s and bytes happens by applying appropriate character encoding, and it can damage binary data passed through `FileWriter`.